# Curious case that filter() not behaving as expected

Tags: r, filter

I refer to the book R for data science https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html the program to check how many flights with departure time earlier than 500 each day.

from the text:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
not_cancelled <- flights %>% 
  filter(!is.na(dep_delay), !is.na(arr_delay))

not_cancelled %>% 
  group_by(year, month, day) %>% 
  summarise(n_early = sum(dep_time < 500))
```

-> 365 x 4

however, an alternative code:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
not_cancelled <- flights %>% 
  filter(!is.na(dep_delay), !is.na(arr_delay))

not_cancelled %>% 
  group_by(year, month, day) %>% 
  select(year:day, dep_time) %>%
  filter(dep_time < 500) %>%
  count()
```

-> cannot produce the same result. instead, the output is 348 x 4.

I cannot figure out the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the second one remove all of the zero days before it produces the result. There are 17 days with zero counts in the first one which accounts for the difference.

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
not_cancelled <- flights %>% 
  filter(!is.na(dep_delay), !is.na(arr_delay))


tmp1 <- not_cancelled %>% 
  group_by(year, month, day) %>% 
  summarise(n_early = sum(dep_time < 500))
sum(tmp1$n_early == 0)
# [1] 17


tmp2 <- not_cancelled %>% 
  group_by(year, month, day) %>% 
  select(year:day, dep_time) %>%
  filter(dep_time < 500) %>%
  count()

sum(tmp2$n == 0)
# [1] 0
```

Comment: thanks very much Dave, you are very helpful indeed